# Track a program's memory & CPU usage with perfmon

Tags: memory, windows-vista, process, perfmon

I'm trying to track a process on system running Windows Vista, I tried creating a user Data Collection Set in Vista's "Reliability and Performance Monitor" (perfmon). What I did is the following:

1. Under "Data Collector Sets" -> "User Defined" -> Right click and "New" -> "Data   Collector Set"
2. In the wizard I chose "Create Manually" -> Tick "Performance Counters" -> Click the "Add..." button
3. Choose "Process" -> "% Processor Time" (Or any other counter for that matter), Choose my instance (for example, iexplore) and click "Add >>"
4. Confirm the rest of the wizard and start the set

What happens is that the set runs and creates a log file, but when I stop it and try to open the file, none of the instance-specific counters show up, neither in the graph nor in the legend. If I add a counter with "_Total" as the instance I can get results.
I've also tried adding all counters for a specific instance (\Process(iexplore)*), in that case I got results, but they we're for "_Total", not for the specified instance.

General info:
Windows Vista Business 32-Bit
Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E6550 @ 2.33Ghz
2GB Ram

If this is the wrong place to ask this question I apologize and ask that you move it to the correct place

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a display error, counters are there but need to be re-added to the result file manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you have not stopped the Data collector set prior to viewing the result.It is necessary that you stop the Data collector by right clicking and hit "Stop" before you view the collected graph.

Answer (score 0):

An old question without answer, but google link me here.
I've spend some time today trying to understand why I see _Total results instead of my process info. The answer is - all processes are collected in a data collector set, and you need choose/add your process counters later when you view the result.

https://serverfault.com/questions/633320/windows-performance-monitor-fails-to-record-all-instances-of-selected-process

Comment: What does coose mean here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant choose. fixed.